# Travis Android build fails due to "Target id is not valid."

Tags: android, travis-ci

I want to run android tests on a connected device. This is my .travis.yml file:

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8

env:
  global:
   - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=10

before_cache:
  - cd ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gradle/caches/
  - find . -name "*.lock" -exec rm -rfv {} \;
  - cd ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}

cache:
  directories:
    - ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gradle/caches/
    - ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/gradle/wrapper/dists/

notifications:
  email: false

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - build-tools-25.0.2
    - platform-tools
    - tools
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22

install:
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.2"
  - echo yes | sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.2"
  # Show version and download Gradle Wrapper if it's not already cached
  - ./gradlew --version
  # Check components status
  - sdkmanager --list || true

  # Emulator Management: Create, Start and Wait
before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-22 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script:
  - android list target
  - ./gradlew build connectedCheck test jacocoTestReport

after_script:
  # Show lint results
  - cat ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/*/build/reports/lint-results.xml

after_success:
- bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Here is the build log https://travis-ci.org/mueller-ma-bot/openhab.android/builds/311512604?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this line](https://travis-ci.org/mueller-ma-bot/openhab.android/builds/311512604#L1542) in the build log:

> Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 22, revision 2'; it
>   depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was
>   not installed.

Install missing platform:

```
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - build-tools-25.0.2
    - platform-tools
    - tools
    - android-22
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-22
```